# VS 2010 Error Opening Design View

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, design-view

There is no editor available for 'file path here'. Make sure the application for file type (.vb) is installed.

This is the error that I get when I try to open a project I did a while back in VB. I tried a C# project and I can open the form for viewing fine, but for some reason VB won't work? Any ideas? I really don't want to do a repair on the whole application as it takes a while and I'm not even sure I have the ISO right now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the compile mode of the object. If it is not set to "compile" then VS gets a bit weird about opening it up.